# How to create IFrame dynamically in runtime in loop in MVC

Tags: javascript, iframe, model-view-controller

I have a view in MVC  in which iframe needs to be created on runtime inside a for loop. Each iframe has a different source. Please can anyone suggest a solution with sample code. Thanxx
I tried the below code but its not working..

```
<div class="width_100" id="div3">

     @{  for (int i = 0; i < datatable1.Rows.Count; i++)
      {

          <script type="text/javascript">
              window.onload = function () {
                  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                  iframe.frameBorder = 0;
                  iframe.width = "300px";
                  iframe.height = "250px";
                  iframe.id = "randomid";
                  iframe.setAttribute("@datatable1.Rows[i]["UploadTitle"].ToString()", "");
                  document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(iframe);
               }
          </script>

      }
      }

  }

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using Javascript at all?

Comment: Please can you give me another solution.. Help appreciated Thanks.I found this piece of code while browsing for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Javascript at all.

Instead, you can write regular `<iframe>` tags in your HTML inside the loop.

Comment: Now I am facing another issue in the same screen..I have one iframe  which is the main document     <iframe id="id1" src="@(ViewBag.FileSrc)" name="I1" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" marginwidth ="0" marginheight="0" style="border:none"/>.. Then after this, I am giving code to add iframes in loop.. Now the issue is first one is displaying and the rest are not displaying. Please help

Comment: How to position these iframes in for loop because I think they are overlapping  with the first one..Help !!

Comment: Use the dev tools inspector to see what is happening.